# Postgres AWR report (Performance) - Sampling time vs Sampling size

Tags: postgresql

We are currently migrating from Oracle to Postgres and would like to have the AWR report generated equivalent to Oracle for analysis in case of issues.

Have successfully implemented Postgres AWR report generation referring below link
https://dbsguru.com/configure-and-monitor-using-pg_profile-in-postgresql/

Per link, a cronjob is scheduled once in 5 minutes to create samples (equivalent to snapshot) and report generation is carried out based on needs with difference between 2 samples

Would like to know from expert DB on the best sampling time to be configured in order to get a useful AWR report (i.e, report is useful to find the root cause for any issue reported in db)

Appreciate your support.

Looking for experitise help on best way to retrieve AWR report or in case current procedure followed is correct, then comments on the sampling time.